# /page_id/feed giving error 403 while publishing feed to a public page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As per the latest Facebook updates post to another user's (B) wall using feed is not allowed. The workaround as per my study is to use "TO" parameter if the session user_id (A) is different than the one whose wall is to be updated (B). I tried and it is working fine. The only issue is that the post is private and is not visible to A's friends.

The same "TO" doesnot work when I post onto a public page using page_id. I tried using /page_id/feed using page access token which worked but it posts onto page on behalf of page. I want to post onto B's wall which is a public page on behalf of a user (A). This is not working.

I have tried using app_id also, even that is not working.

To summarize, https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed?access_token={page_access_token}... works but posts on page on behalf of page itself. I need to post on behalf of session user.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to clarity your problem. You can use user_access_token post to page, and you are the admin on the page also, right?

Comment: The post is happening thru web application. If I use graph explorer and issue the following:

Comment: The post is happening thru web application. If I use graph explorer and issue the following:/<page_id>/feed?link=http://staging.vobolo.com&access_token=<user_access_token>&message=message&name=name&caption=caption&description=description&client_id=<app_client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret> it works but when doing the same thru my app it shows error 400 Java IO exception. If it is not allowed the error raised should be 403 and not 400. Since it is a public page anyone should be allowed to post.

Comment: Why you need client_id and client_secret to do publish? Moreover, Message and Link parameters is enough.

Comment: That I have tried, but in vain. What I need to do is to publish a feed on a public page on behalf of a Facebook user who has already authenticated my app. I have user Id, user access token for the user who has already authenticated the app. I also have page id and page access token for the public page. I also have application access token. I have been doing this in the past by using pageid of the public page but now that stopped working, I don't know why.

Comment: May be you can try to copy the access token(which was not working on Java), and paste to graph API explorer on "Access token" field. Then request POST to page API. See whether it can work or not.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with pageid and page access token. It reported error Can't validate the access token "error":{"code":190,"error_subcode":467,"message":"Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.","type":"OAuthException". On investigation, I found its a known bug reported long back (14 june, 2012) at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/319702504783667/. However, could not find the latest update. But surprisingly, it worked yesterday in explorer. I can see the post on my public page.

Comment: Can you try with User Access Token? You should always test with your user access token first, not page token(limited function). Also, you can check your User Access Token on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, make sure the token have the publish_stream, status_update...etc permissions.